# how to register devicetoken to userid for ios push notification

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

we are trying to send push notification messages from apex trigger and we are following this site https://salesforcesos.com/ios/service-sdk/1.0.0/service_sdk_ios/notifications.htm.

through console we can send push notifications using device token but in apex trigger we have to use userid. 
my question where device token is mapped to user ? who is mapping  and how is mapping?

Thanks,
Malli